# Orchard 1.7 - Add Image Upload field to Custom Form

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I am building a Student Registration form using Orchard.CustomForms module.

I have got most of the fields working except for Student Image.

I tried using Orchard.Module.Contrib.ImageField & Orchard.Module.Contrib.MediaPickerField modules but don't see this in the list of fields.

The same goes for other attachments (pdf, word). Is there any module working with Orchard 1.7 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those were not designed to upload files from the front-end. You'll have to build your own, or find another one on the gallery, if there is one.

Comment: I searched the gallery but could not find any. If you know of any such modules, it would be of great help.